# How can I insert into vector with a class including condition variable?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, c++17

I try to insert into vector with a class including condition variable,my code as follow:

```cpp
class LockRequest {
   public:
    LockRequest( ) : granted_(false) {}
    bool granted_;
  };

  class LockRequestQueue {
   public:
    std::list<LockRequest> request_queue_;
    std::condition_variable cv_;  // for notifying blocked transactions on this rid
    bool upgrading_ = false;
  };

int main(){
    LockRequestQueue request;
    std::vector<LockRequestQueue> vecs;
    vecs.push_back(request);
    return 0;
}
```

but I get error.When I remove the condition variable `cv_`,the result is correct.How can I fix this problem??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::condition_variable` is not

- copy constructible,
- move constructible,
- copy assignable or
- move assignable.

**So adding it directly to any class as a member would also add those qualifications to that class too**.
In order to avoid that, we use an extra level of indirection, for example, a `std::unique_ptr` to hold a pointer to it.

```cpp
class LockRequestQueue {
public:

    LockRequestQueue() // make a condition variable and assign it to the unique_ptr
        :cv_(std::make_unique<std::condition_variable>())
    {}

    std::list<LockRequest> request_queue_;
    std::unique_ptr<std::condition_variable> cv_;  //notice the unique_ptr
    bool upgrading_ = false;
};
```

And now, in our `main()` function, we use `std::move` to push to the vector since `std::unique_ptr` itself is not copy constructible:

```cpp
int main()
{

    LockRequestQueue request;
    std::vector<LockRequestQueue> vecs;
    vecs.push_back(std::move(request)); //notice the std::move
    return 0;
}
```